# Is it possible to create Main Activity in the WorkManager's doWork()?

Tags: android, android-workmanager

If application's activity enqueues periodic work and is destroyed, is it possible for the periodic work to launch main activity?

I assigned the application context to the context variable in the constructor and tried to use app context through Handler class in a doWork() method.

I succeed in using application context in doWork().
but I don't know how to recreate main Activity. I mean I want to start my application in work thread.

```
//java
public Result doWork() {

    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String str = "BackGround Service running... " + called;
            Toast.makeText(mContext, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*
            I want to run my application again in here 
            */                                  
        }
    }, 0);
    return Result.success();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//java
public Result doWork() {
  Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String str = "BackGround Service running... " + called;
        Toast.makeText(mContext, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent( mContext ,MainActivity.class); 
        mContext.startActivity(intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));                              
    }
  }, 0);
  return Result.success();
}
```

It works... is this the best way?

Comment: @MalavanRockzz Thanks, have a great day! :)

Comment: This won't work on newer versions of Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/background-starts